# Mi codigo no me deja actualizar los datos en la BDD (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, sql

**Aca se encuentra armada la clase y la funcion editar() donde cambiar los datos, intente por varios caminos tamien utilizando el mysqli_prepare sin embargo no se si el error se encuentra aqui**

```
<?php
        require_once("conexion.php");
        class Asociados extends Conexion{
            public $id_Asociado;
            public $nombre;
            public $apellido;
            public $es_Donante;
            public $fecha_Nacimiento;
            public $enfermedades;
    public function editar()
            {
                $this->conectar_DB();
                $editar = mysqli_query($this->enlace,"UPDATE asociado SET nombre = '$this->nombre' , apellido= '$this->apellido' , esDonante= '$this->es_Donante' , fecha_Nacimiento= '$this->fecha_Nacimiento' , enfermedades= '$this->enfermedades' WHERE id_Asociado= '$this->id_Asociado' "); 
                if ($editar){
                    echo "<script> alert('Datos actualizados') </script>";
                    header("location: datos-personales.php");
                    }else{
                     echo "<script> alert('Error no se pudieron actualizar los datos')</script>";
                    }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**Y esta es la parte donde esta el formulario y los datos que se enviaran**

```
<form class="formulario" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_Asociado">
                    <label>Nombre</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" required><br>
                    <label>Apellido</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="apellido" required><br>
                    <label>Fecha nacimiento</label><br>
                    <input  type="date" name="fecha_Nacimiento" required><br>
                    <label>Es donante</label><br>
                    <select  name="donante" required>
                        <option value="SI">SI</option>
                        <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <label>Posee enfermedades cronicas</label><br>
                    <select  name="enfermedades" required>
                        <option value="SI">SI</option>
                        <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <div class="b-actualizar">
                        <input type="submit" value="Actualizar datos" name="actualizar">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <?php
include_once("asociados.php");
if (isset($_POST["actualizar"])) {
    $editar = new Asociados;
    $editar->id_Asociado = $_POST["id_Asociado"];
    $editar->nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $editar->apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $editar->fecha_Nacimiento = $_POST["fecha_Nacimiento"];
    $editar->es_Donante = $_POST["donante"];
    $editar->enfermedades = $_POST["enfermedades"];
    }

    $editar->editar()
?>
```

**COMO BIEN DICE EN EL TITULO ESTE CODIGO NO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE YA QUE NO ME ACTUALIZA LOS DATOS. PD: seguramente existan muchos errores pero este es mi primer proyecto soy principiante**

Comment: Hola. Pon un título adecuado a tu pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Parece que empezaste a redactar la pregunta desde el título ¿? Dinos también qué mensaje muestra tu código actualmente para tener una idea de cuál puede ser el error. Y dinos si esa es toda tu clase. Yo no veo el constructor de la misma, por lo que sus propiedades podrían ser nulas.

Comment: @A.Cedano este es mi primer post pido disculpas de antemano, resulta que ser que coloque un titulo distinto nose porque se puso ese, siguiendo con la consulta creo que ya empezamos con uno de los problemas ya que no tengo metodo constructor :( y no aparece ningun tipo de error, yo al darle al boton de actualizar o submit la funcion entra por el camino del si correctamente sin embargo no cumple su rol de actualizar los datos. Con respecto a lo de la clase no mande toda la clase ya que las demas son otras funciones al igual que esta la cual no tienen relevancia

Comment: Ya, acabo de ver que asignas las propiedades de la clase a mano... No me queda claro cuál de los dos `alert` se muestra en el código actual ¿? Sugiero que pongas esto al inicio de tu `php` para ver los errores: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @A.Cedano como te comente entra por el camino del si es decir que el `alert` dice que los datos fueron actualizados.
Perdon la ignorancia que tan mal esta en este caso a ver pueso las propiedades a mano, recomendas que lo vuelva a hacer con el metodo constructor correspondiente?

Comment: ¿Estás pasando datos diferentes o que no violen alguna restricción de tipo UNIQUE o PRIMARY KEY en la tabla? En ambos casos el UPDATE no ocurrirá.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar esto: `echo "<script> alert('Datos actualizados') </script>";` por esto: `printf("<script> alert('Datos actualizados. Filas actualizadas: %s') </script>",$this->enlace->affected_rows);`

Comment: ya te cercioraste que tus datos llegan a tu Update?,  mejor dicho tus datos llegan a tu función editar?

Comment: prueba enviando datos quemados ósea datos por defecto  y no variables en tu update y si esto funciona entonces el proceso de actualización esta bien y lo que pasa es que no están llegando tus datos a la función editar

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo probe y efectivamente me sale que no se actualizo ninguna fila

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos hola, si probe directamente actualizandolos desde phpmyadmin y no hubo ningun problema, ahora deberia verificar desde el codigo pasandolo directamente

Comment: @LuisAgustínLuna verifica desde tu código mandando tu update con datos ya definidos  y no con variables

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos MUCHAS GRACIAS, acabo de descubrir que el problema es que el `WHERE id_Asociado=...` no estaba funcionando ya que no le esta llegando ese parametro, ahora queda buscar porque no le llega

Comment: @LuisAgustínLuna Solo el id no esta llegando, los demás datos están llegando bien?

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos si y me parece raro ya que los demas llegan todos perfectamente, asi que estoy buscando y tratando de encontrar el error

Comment: @LuisAgustínLuna El id esta en tu formulario por defecto?,  como lo agregas?

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos el id viene por método GET desde otra pagina pero ya logre que funcionara creo que habia una mala sintaxis en una linea pero ya esta funcionando al 100% muchas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: Puede que el `input` que recogía el `id_Asociado` estuviera vacío ¿? Al ser oculto: `<input type="hidden" name="id_Asociado">` ese `input` no da la posibilidad de que se introduzca un valor en él, a no ser que lo hicieras de forma programática. Por otra parte, hay muchas cosas por refinar en tu código: tu consulta es susceptible a ataques de *inyección SQL* y tu modelo de datos no es conforme a la realidad, una clase `Asociados` no debería extender de `Conexion`, son dos entidades que no tienen nada que ver, desde el punto de vista metafísico.